# Crash when detect wifi state at android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE

Tags: android, wifi, intentfilter

I want to get `the wifi state` when there is a change in wifi state as follows:

**Manifest:**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />          
</intent-filter>
```

**Service:**

```
WifiManager mainWifiObj;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = mainWifiObj.getConnectionInfo();
        String WifiState = "";
        if (mainWifiObj.isWifiEnabled()) {
            WifiState = "Wifi On";
        } else {
            WifiState = "Wifi Off";
        }
    }
```

But it crashes at `WifiInfo wifiInfo = mainWifiObj.getConnectionInfo();`  What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized the `WifiManager` object. do it in onReceive method in this manner

```
mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```